# How to properly organize the verification of the output value of the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

There is a code that was created for making calculations. In the **CentrifugalLiquidInjector** class, we perform all calculations that will be divided into different functions, for example, take the **relative_length_tangential_hole** f
unction, the output value of which should be in the range from **1.5** to **6.0**,this value is specified as constants in the **RelativeLength** class.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum


class RelativeLength(Enum):
    MAX_RELATIVE_LENGTH = 6
    MIN_RELATIVE_LENGTH = 1.5


@dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)
class CentrifugalLiquidInjector:
    diameter_input_tangential_holes: float
    length_input_tangential_holes: float

    @property
    def relative_length_tangential_hole(self) -> float:
        value_relative_length = self.length_input_tangential_holes / self.diameter_input_tangential_holes
        if RelativeLength.MIN_RELATIVE_LENGTH.value <= value_relative_length <= \
                RelativeLength.MAX_RELATIVE_LENGTH.value:
            return value_relative_length
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Значение {value_relative_length} относительной длины тангенциального отверстия, "
                             f"не входит в диапозон [{RelativeLength.MIN_RELATIVE_LENGTH.value}..."
                             f"{RelativeLength.MAX_RELATIVE_LENGTH.value}]")
```

Is the check for hits in the range done correctly, or is it more correct to organize it in some other way?

Comment: This seems to be fine. It is a bit questionable whether an enum is a good place to store these type of constants: enums are usually compared directly to an enum value (i.e., using `==` and `!=`), which `value_relative_length` is not (which is of course why the `.value` attribute is necessary). As an alternative, a dataclass `RelativeLength` with the two constants could also work, or even just the two constants as global variables.